# If the answerer answers the question in the comments of their answer, should the OP accept that answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer

Let's say the question is:

> **How do I open Terminal Quickly?**
>
> I have been looking for an easy way or short-cut to open the Terminal quickly, so I don't have to find it in the Dash.

And the answerer answers:

> You can open Terminal easily by finding it in the Dash, or you can pin it to the Unity sidebar. Both are quick and easy to use.

However, Person 1 says in the comments of that answer:

> Is there a way to use the keyboard to initiate the Terminal?

And the answerer then replies,

> Yes, you are able to use Ctrl + Alt + T on your keyboard as a short-cut.

So technically, the answerer answered the question, but in the comment and not in the actual answer. Does that make the answer the right one? And should the OP denote in the comments of the answer that the comment was the correct solution?

How should this situation be handled?

Comment: Here's a good example from the original SO launch blog post that's good to know too that talks about this very problem: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html

Comment: Nice link. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, but...

If you can edit their answer to include the comments, that'd be great. Comments are second class citizens here on Ask Ubuntu - they can (and are) deletable at any time, for almost any reason. So just keep that in mind.

<sub>Someday  I'll write a script to purge all comments from the year 2010 - nobody will miss 'em - I hope. ;)</sub>

Comment: Haha very true. Great answer, perhaps the OP could advise them to edit the comment in? Thanks very much. Also, was I right to ask this type of question on Meta. In experienced when it comes to this site :S

Comment: You asked in the right place. :)

Comment: Let me just point out the 'comment' is actually a second question.  And that should mean that the answer to the original question was correct, even though the asker didn't know enough to ask everything they should have up front.